# RESTful request in ajax and react

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

good day, im trying to consume a web service in react, but im having problems with the ajax function, i'm not sure if is working my code is this:

```
prox= {"email":email, "password": password};
//tag comment
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: (web service url),
  data: JSON.stringify(prox),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json',   
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({success: true, result: data});
    alert("success");
    this.setState({prueba: 'success'});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function() {
    this.setState({failure: true});
    alert("failure");
    this.setState({prueba: 'failure'});
  }.bind(this)
});
```

but i dont have any alert, when i click the button only re-render the form, the function handdle submit works, i try it putting a confirm() in the space where the //tag comment is and the confirm pop up, but the alerts dont, i think that i have an error in the function or something, thank's for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some extensive research i see that my real problem whas the same origin policy, now im working fine in the localhost version of the project, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run the script but just looking at it I imagine the problem could be your `bind(this)`

`this.setState` to me should be an error “**is not a function**” as `this` is not the react object. To get an alert try placing the alert as the first state.

To be sure just look at your browser console.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his context bind.  `this` still refers to the instance of the React component.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its working for the most part.  I threw it into a JSBin and nothing seems to be out of the ordinary.

http://jsbin.com/rulaguxote/1/edit?html,js,output

I kept your JSX mostly the same, and added a few things in the component to help you visualize its state.  Click the button to send a fake ajax request.  Depending on the state, it will either send back an HTTP status of 200 or 400 (success or failure).  This way, you can see how the `success()` and `error()` functions behave.

Another thing to note:  If you are concerned that your `.bind(this)` is the reason your code is not working, you can specify the context like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : '/test',
    data        : JSON.stringify(prox),
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    context     : this, //use this instead of .bind
    success     : function (data) {
        this.setState({success : true, failure : false});
        alert("success");
    },
    error       : function () {
        this.setState({failure : true, success : false});
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.